# JVM hangs on exit with java dataflow-sdk 1.9.1 and hbase 1.0.0 (but not with previous hbase libraries)

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

We use Dataflow and Bigtable heavily, and we encountered a strange issue recently.

With Dataflow SDK 1.9.1 and bigtable-hbase-dataflow 1.0.0, our Java code that reads Bigtable runs perfectly fine (i.e., dataflow pipeline succeeds normally) but the JVM seems to hang on exiting. We tried it on multiple local machines (OS X) and GCP VMs, and it always hangs on exit.
If we add `System.exit(0)` at the end of the main method, luckily it terminates normally so we can getting around the issue in this manner, but we could not quite figure out why this is happening.

When we tried Dataflow SDK 1.9.1 with other hbase versions (specifically, 0.9.7.1, 1.0.0-pre1, and 1.0.0-pre4), this issue goes away.

As for the Java code (for Dataflow pipeline), it looks like the following (we simplified things to reproduce this error multiple times, and this happens regardless whether the scan job returns empty PCollection or not).

```
// ... some Dataflow pipeline options are set prior to this step.
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setCacheBlocks(false).setMaxVersions(1); // Disable caching and read only the latest cell.
scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes("x")); // Read only 'x' column family.
scan.setStartRow(Bytes.toBytes("prefix1")).setStopRow(Bytes.toBytes("prefix2"));
try {
  long tsBegin = DateTime.parse("2018-03-01T00:00:00Z").getMillis();
  long tsEnd = DateTime.parse("2018-03-01T01:00:00Z").getMillis();
  scan.setTimeRange(tsBegin, tsEnd);
} catch (IOException e) {
  // If unable to set time range, do not run this job as it may read the entire UPT and affect production.
  LOG.error("Unable to set Time Range for Bt Scan object.", e);
  return;
}

CloudBigtableScanConfiguration btConfig = new 
CloudBigtableScanConfiguration.Builder()
                              .withProjectId("projectId")
                              .withInstanceId("instanceId")
                              .withTableId("tableId")
                              .withScan(scan)
                              .build();
pipeline.apply(Read.from(CloudBigtableIO.read(btConfig)));
System.out.println("before run");
PipelineResult pipelineResult = pipeline.run();
System.out.println("after run");
// This hangs on exit.
// System.exit(0); would work fine and exit.
// throw new RuntimeException("test re"); this will throw an exception, but will hang (provided that System.exit() above is not present).
```

```

Here's what we used in gradle dependencies. 
Again, with previous (but deprecated) versions of bigtable-hbase-dafatflow libraries, we do not see this issue. 

    `compile 'com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all:1.9.1'
    compile 'com.google.cloud.bigtable:bigtable-hbase-dataflow:1.0.0'`

I'm wondering if Bigtable or Dataflow team can reproduce this error on their end (just reading any Bigtable instance/table gives us this error, regardless of the Scan results), as it appears that something in hbase 1.0.0 (that isn't in previous versions) may be causing the issue.
We used Java 1.8.0 (0_151) and Gradle versions both 3.1 and 4.3.1 for reproducing the errors.

Updated for those with similar issues:

As pointed out below, after taking thread dump, we found the following, among others (`grep lmax`):

```
"pool-4-thread-1" #23 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fd8d4d88000 nid=0x150f runnable [0x000070000b016000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:338)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.lmax.disruptor.SleepingWaitStrategy.applyWaitMethod(SleepingWaitStrategy.java:82)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.lmax.disruptor.SleepingWaitStrategy.waitFor(SleepingWaitStrategy.java:55)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.lmax.disruptor.ProcessingSequenceBarrier.waitFor(ProcessingSequenceBarrier.java:56)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Take a full thread stack trace when it hangs, and check which thread is doing what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem introduced based on Cloud Bigtable clien's dependency on opencensus stackdriver in v 1.0.0.  If you would like to confirm this, you can take a thread dump; you would see an entry with lmax disruptor if this was indeed the case.

I would suggest that you upgrade to 1.2.0 and use Beam / Dataflow v2.  If you can't do that, then downgrade to 1.0.0-pre4.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply! What you suggested seems to be the issue we are having (will add the details to the original post). We'll probably use 1.0.0-pre4 for now. Thank you!